# Trouble solving $y' y''=x^2+x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I'm stuck on solving $$y' y''=x^2+x$$ with $(x,y,y')=(0,1,2)$.

Here's what I've tried

$$\int y' y'' \ dx = \int (x^2+x)\  dx$$
by substitution
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2=\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^2}{2}+C$$

from initial conditions $C=2$

$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2=\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^2}{2}+2$$

now I am supposed to obtain $dy/dx$ but I am stuck. What to do? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Solving for $y'$ requires to take a square root and integrate. The appropriate sign can be obtained from your initial conditions a t $x=0$, namely $y(0)=1$ and $y'(0)=2>0$.

Comment: Multiply both sides by 2 and take the square root will give y' as a function of x.  Integrate again to get y.

Comment: The integral is not elementary.  It can be done using elliptic integral functions.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Elliptic functions!! This problem is given in chapter 1.4 of my intro to DE book. See because I don't know how to integrate the root of a cubic, I can't even determine the second integration constant associated with integrating $dy/dx$.

Comment: So you should leave the answer in the form of an integral.

Answer (score 1):

$y'=\sqrt{\frac{2x^3}{3}+x^2+4}$.  Off hand I don't think you can get a nice integral.